# find + xargs + ctags is somehow missing tags for entire subdirectories

Tags: find, xargs, ctags

(I am using RHEL7).

For Vim I create a `tags` file with `find` and `ctags`, running it from the directory which contains my many directories of Python packages source code.

Initially I was doing this:

```
find . -name \*.py | xargs ctags
```

but at some point I found that it was missing some entire packages.

Strangely it got fixed when I decided to skip all the test directories with:

```
find . -name \*.py -not \( -path \*/tests\*/\* \) | xargs ctags
```

I recently added some more Python packages and now this fix is skipping some directories again.

BTW, this works:

```
find . -name \*.py > files_for_ctags.txt; ctags -L files_for_ctags.txt
```

so for now it will be my solution.

But it would be nice to understand why the `xargs` version sometimes skips and entire directory of tags.

Any suggestions?

Comment: give examples of paths of missing packages. What happens if you try `find . -name \*.py -print0 | xargs -0 ctags` ?

Comment: I gave your `-print0` suggestion a try @jhnc but it did not fix the issue. Re your question: all directories have a similar name format and dirtree shape (they are all Python packages after all). There is no obvious reason to me why some should not be included. For example, a path that I see missing just now is not even the first or last in alphabetical order (well it might have been the case that some clipping or overwriting is happening, but it seems not). Again, the version which pipes into `files_for_ctags.txt` works so I don't know why the `xargs` version doesn't.

Comment: How about `find . -name \*.py | ctags -L -`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

find may send too many lines to xargs via the pipe.
You can confirm it with `find . -name \*.py | wc -l`.

In the case, xargs launches ctags process more than twice.
The nth launched ctags process may overwrite the tags file generated by (n-1)th launched ctags process. This may be the trick of skipping you observed.

As I wrote in the comment, you can avoid the skipping with `find . -name \*.py | ctags -L -`.

There is one known issue about "-L -".
If find sends a file name starting with "--" to ctags, it can be a trouble; ctags recognizes it as an option.
See https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/issues/1883 .

Comment: Yes this worked! I checked the hypothesis of multiple `ctags` by running `rm tags; find . -name \*.py | xargs ctags --append` and indeed I see all the tags I was expecting. Without the `--append` a lot of the tags are missing (which I now presume is because `xargs` caused multiple launches of `ctags` and therefore I was actually seeing only the results of the final `ctags`).
Many thanks :-)